# php mailer doesn't send email in some cases

Tags: php, email, send, mailer

Can any help me regarding php mailer..The code I use is not working in some cases, I dont know why...When the user use the form twice, php mailer is not working....Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
    $errors = '';
    $myemail = 'juan91delacruz@gmail.com';//<-----Put Your email address `enter code here`here.
    if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
        empty($_POST['email']) || 
        empty($_POST['address']) ||
        empty($_POST['contact']) ||
        empty($_POST['pick_up_date']) ||
        empty($_POST['time']) ||
        empty($_POST['return_date']) ||
        empty($_POST['time2']))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];  
    $email_address = $_POST['email']; 
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $choose_car = $_POST['choose_car'];
    $pick_up_date = $_POST['pick_up_date'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $am_pm = $_POST['am_pm'];
    $return_date = $_POST['return_date'];
    $time2 = $_POST['time2'];
    $am_pm2 = $_POST['am_pm2'];
    $message = $_POST['message']; 

    if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
    $email_address))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
    }

    if( empty($errors))
    {
        $to = $myemail; 
        $email_subject = "Reservation from: $name";
        $email_body = "New reservation received. ".
        " Here are the details:\n \n    NAME: $name \n 
        EMAIL ADD: $email_address \n 
        ADDRESS: $address \n 
        CONTACT NUMBER: $contact \n 
        CHOOSEN CAR: $choose_car \n 
        PICK UP DATE: $pick_up_date $time $am_pm  \n 
        RETURN DATE: $return_date $time2 $am_pm2  \n 
        MESSAGE: $message"; 

        $headers = "From: $email_address\n"; 
        //$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
        //redirect to the 'thank you' page
        header('Location: thank-you.php');
    } 
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact form handler</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
    <?php
    echo nl2br($errors);
    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

I hope anyone can help me...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: what doesn't work? what's the error?

Comment: there's no error....it works but can't send a message using the form....

Comment: You're best just using a third party library like PHPMailer.

Comment: Can you elaborate please....I think i'm using PHPMailer

Comment: You're using the `mail()` function which comes with PHP. Try using https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer instead.

Comment: Try `include 'thank-you.php'; return;` in place of `header('Location: thank-you.php');`

Comment: I'll try..I hope it works....

Comment: can you show what the code looks like?....thank you